# How to select elements by it's displayed text c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm currently dealing with a dynamic table that is constantly changing XPaths and Selectors. Because of this, I want to select elements by using it's displayed text. Is there any way to do this?

I've seen some post where this has been suggested, but it doesn't work for me:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Lager av råvarer og halvfabrikata')]"));
```

I cannot select the element by it's class "ng-binding" because there are several elements that has the same name.

```
<u class="ng-binding">Lager av råvarer og halvfabrikata</u>
```

[The element I'm trying to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Ykt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath

```
//u[contains(@class,'ng-binding')][contains(text(), 'Lager av råvarer og halvfabrikata')]

//u[contains(text(), 'Lager av råvarer og halvfabrikata')]
```

Also use wait if necessary

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Unfortunately it did not work.

I got this error even tho the element is visible:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 'element not visible.

The XPath for this element is: //*[@id="differences0101"]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/div[4]/u

The id comes from the table where the element is located

Comment: Try javascriptexecutor